# SmsRetrieverHelper Timed out waiting for SMS

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am using Firebase OTP to verify the phone number, but I got this error when trying to get the OTP SMS code to my phone, [SmsRetrieverHelper]. I timed out. I got this error when I tried waiting for an SMS.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit this issue
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4916
this error has multiple reasons.
In my case the OTP message was too long (67 chars).