# FirebaseAuth SMS verification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing a problem in Firebase not sending the verification code to the number: phone number = "+970xxxxxxxxx".

My code

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: number,
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential)  {
  },
  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;

    });
    print(e.message);
    if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
      print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
    }
  },
  codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;

    });
    await Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return verifyCode(
        verification: verificationId.toString(),
        registerModel: user,
      );
    }));
  },
  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
);}
```

My dependencies:

```
firebase_auth: ^4.1.1

firebase_core: ^2.1.1

 minSdkVersion 19

 targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

 multiDexEnabled true
```

W/FirebaseAuth( 3798): [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.

I'm using Flutter.

Comment: whats the problem here and whats the error you are getting? please include it in your post

Comment: @john 
I did not see any error, but it does not send the code to the entered phone number

Comment: can you enable phone authentication sign method on firebase

Comment: @SachinKumawat  yes

Comment: try change minSdkVersion 21

Comment: Firebase verifyPhoneNumber  function call in try-catch function with await and check error

Comment: @SachinKumawat i change minSdkVersion 21  and add try -catch but it didn't send the code and it didn't show me any errors

Comment: then you check configuration of firebase that connected or not

Comment: @SachinKumawat firebase connected

Comment: Have a look  at the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530885/18265638), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468064/18265638) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535667/firebase-phone-auth-wont-send-me-the-sms-with-my-code/52834971#52834971)